# Really long listview = Blank page on iPhone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I set up an example page here:
http://jsbin.com/opavi5/3

On any desktop browser, the page displays properly. But on iPhone2G, it is just a blank page. If I shorten the list, the page displays fine on iPhone. It also displays fine on Android phones.

If I change the script references to alpha 3, the page displays fine on the iPhone. So some change has broken long lists with the iPhone, but I have no idea where the problem is.

Edit:
Also, as a sidenote. This is a very simple list. So I had to make it around 550 rows to break the iPhone. On my more complicated page, the page is broken on iPhone with 300 rows (possibly less).

Is there a way to increase timeout in jquery-1.5.2.js?

Source:http://forum.jquery.com/topic/really-long-listview-blank-page-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

This is a timeout issue and you're also running out of ram space the application needs. I would suggest pagination or load the frame of the page and add the listview incremental via ajax.

Comment: or even split the view server-side and add a "more" link at the end of each list

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the listview documentation on the site I noticed they also have a [performance test](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/content/../../docs/lists/../../docs/pages/../../docs/lists/lists-performance.html) which loads 500 list items in a list. So I see no reason as to why you can have a list that long but I have a follow up question.

What's inside this list? Images? if it's just text you might be able to display it.

I would suggest running the performance test on the jQM site on your device and test the performance before making any changes